# How do I call an Access sub from Excel when Access is declared as a Database and not an Object?

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

```
    Sub exportRecords()

    Dim report As Worksheet
    Set report = Sheets("Report")

    Dim lastrow, x As Integer
        With report
            lastrow = report.Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        End With

    Dim db As Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

    Set db = OpenDatabase("\\~\myDB.accdb")
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("TblData", dbOpenTable)

    For x = 2 To lastrow
        If report.Range("AI" & x) = "MSH" Then
            rs.AddNew
            rs.Fields("Date") = report.Range("A" & x).Value
            rs.Fields("AgentName") = report.Range("E" & x).Value
            rs.Fields("Tardy") = report.Range("S" & x).Value
            rs.Fields("Comments") = report.Range("X" & x).Value
            rs.Update
        Else
        End If
    Next x

    '****THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO RUN THE ACCESS SUB/MACRO****

    rs.Close
    db.Close


    End Sub
```

I am familiar with how to call an external sub if Access is declared as an object:

```
Dim accApp As Object
Set accApp = CreateObject("Access.Application")
accApp.OpenCurrentDatabase("\\~\myDB.accdb")
accApp.DoCmd.RunMacro "Modulename.Macroname"
```

But if I go that route then I'm unsure how to add the records using DAO like I am below. Is there any other way to call the sub?

Comment: Your title seems to point toward confusion with late vs early binding. The code is identical in both cases, the only difference is that when you code against `Object` VBA resolves the member calls at run-time, whereas with early-binding they're resolved at compile-time (hence you get IntelliSense & auto-completion).

Comment: Just do `Dim accApp As Access.Application`. Done.

Comment: I had to tweak that a bit and do `Set accApp = CreateObject("Access.Application")` and added `accApp.Application.Run "modulename.macroname"` near the end but now I am getting `Run time error Method Run of object "Application" failed` I am looking into now

Comment: If you're early binding, just `Set accApp = New Access.Application`.... there is no reason to change any of the `.OpenCurrentDatabase` or `.DoCmd.RunMacro` code. *Early/Late-bound code does the exact same identical thing. The **only** difference is that late-bound calls are resolved at run-time*.

Comment: I think I'm almost there...but now I'm getting an error where it can't find the Access sub. It's a Sub, not a Function, and it's in a regular module. Is there a better syntax than what I have above?